# My code works but sometimes gets into an infinite loop

Tags: python

So i got an assignment from school that the code should pick a string, remove the first and the last index, then randomize the middle letters and give back the string with the first and the last index again attached. The word should be at least 4 characters long and schould not give back the original string. It is warking and all, but it after a few attempts at giving a 4 letter word gets into an infinite loop and I can't figure out why. It's a python code. Thank you for your help. Also some variables are in my laguage which shouldn't be a problem...just to clarify the weird variable names.

```
import random
n=0
while n<4:
    slovo=input('Zadajte vase slovo: ')
    n=len(slovo)

l=[]
def shufle(slovo,l):
    for i in range(len(slovo)):
        if i==0:
            continue
        if i==len(slovo)-1:
            continue
        else:
            l.append(slovo[i])
    random.shuffle(l)

while True:
    shufle(slovo,l)
    s=slovo[0]
    for i in l:
        s+=i
    s+=slovo[-1]
    if s==slovo:
        continue
    elif len(s)!=len(slovo):
        continue
    else:
        print(s)
        break
```

Comment: If you get the same word as the original one on the first attempt, you call `shufle` again with the existing `l` list to which you append new letters. The list just gets longer, so `elif len(s)!=len(slovo):` will be True, you `continue` and grow your list infinitely. Don't pass `l` to your function, it has nothing to do in its parameters. Just create the shuffled list inside your function and `return` it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tip: if your function is always expecting the same input for one of its parameters, than that parameter is probably not necessary. This is the case with passing empty lists or similar objects to functions. There was also a check if s and slovo are the same size which is not needed so I removed it. Try this:

```
import random
n=0
while n<4:
    slovo=input('Zadajte vase slovo: ')
    n=len(slovo)

def shufle(slovo):
    l = []
    for i in range(len(slovo)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        if i == len(slovo)-1:
            continue
        else:
            l.append(slovo[i])
    random.shuffle(l)
    return l

while True:
    l = shufle(slovo)
    s = slovo[0]
    for i in l:
        s += i
    s += slovo[-1]
    if s == slovo:
        continue
    else:
        print(s)
        break
```

Comment: Thank you it works now.

Comment: @Eidam Please accept my answer if you found it helpful